# Regex for extracting words before punctuation's

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract phrase which occur before a punctuation but is of the form capitalized words in a phrase.

> **Abstract Algebra**. the area of modern mathematics that considers
>   algebraic structures to be sets with operations defined on them, and
>   extends algebraic concepts usually associated with the real number
>   system to other more general systems, such as groups, rings, fields,
>   modules and vector spaces.
>
> **Algebra.** a branch of mathematics that uses symbols or letters to
>   represent variables, values or numbers, which can then be used to
>   express operations and relationships and to solve equations.
>
> **Algebraic Expression**. a combination of numbers and letters equivalent
>   to a phrase in language, e.g. x2 + 3x - 4.
>
> **Analytic (Cartesian) Geometry:** the study of geometry using a
>   coordinate system and the principles of algebra and analysis, thus
>   defining geometrical shapes in a numerical way and extracting
>   numerical information from that representation.
>
> **Inductive reasoning or logic:** a type of reasoning that involves moving
>   from a set of specific facts to a general conclusion, indicating some
>   degree of support for the conclusion without actually ensuring its
>   truth.

Currently I'm using the following regex:

```
(([? ])([A-Z][a-z\s]+)?([A-Z][a-z\s]+?[.:]))
```

I have two issues with this.

1. I think this is not the optimum way of writing it.
2. Its not capturing the ones where there are more than two words in a phrase

Answer (score 2):

Try `^[A-Z][^.,:';]+`

Explanation:

`^` - beginning of a line

`[A-Z]` - single uppercase character

`[^.,:';]+` - one or more of characters different from `.,:';`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VRYiSk/1)

Answer (score 1):

One reason not matching more than 1 word for the current data is that the pattern starts with `[? ]` which will match either a space or question mark.

You might also omit some of the capturing groups and use a single one. Note that you don't have to make this match `[a-z\s]+?[.:]` non greedy using a `?` because the character class does not contain a `.` or `:`

To get the capitalized words followed by either `.` or `:` you could use:

```
\b([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*)[.:]
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z][a-z]+`
  - `(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching A-Z and 1+ times a-z
- `)` Close group
- `[.:]` Match either `.` or `:`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1D9LYg/1)

If you also want to match words surrounded by `(` and `)` you might use an alternation.

```
\b((?:\([A-Z][a-z]+\)|[A-Z][a-z]+)(?:\s+(?:\([A-Z][a-z]+\)|[A-Z][a-z]+))*)[.:]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1FGi3H/1)